# After upgrade webpack from version 3 to 4 get "[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation"

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-router, webpack-4

After upgrade webpack from version 3 to 4 and third-party packages I get this error:

> [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>
> [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:63)

Webpack.js

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

const conf = {
    entry: {
        'catalog/bonus': './app/Admin/assets/catalog/bonus/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: `${__dirname}/public/assets/admin`,
        publicPath: '/assets/admin/',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            '@src': path.resolve(__dirname)
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
};

if (ENV === 'development') {
    conf.devtool = 'source-map';
}

module.exports = conf;
```

Example of using vue router

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: '/', name: 'main', component: () => import('./components/BonusList')},
        {path: '/create', name: 'create', component: () => import('./components/BonusEdit')},
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes), the component in VueRouter doesn't seem to be a function, therefore not callable . Also the imports don't seem to work, as they return `undefined`.

Have you tried the following?

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import BonusList from './components/BonusList';
import BonusEdit from './components/BonusEdit';

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: '/', name: 'main', component: BonusList},
        {path: '/create', name: 'create', component: BonusEdit},
    ]
});
```